# iPhone Application Name Already Taken

Tags: itunes, developer-program

I have developed an application for which I had registered a name on apple itunes portal. As my application is done now and I needed to upload the binary, I got invalid binary error many times. I thought I should start over the process to create the app again. I deleted the app and tried to create it again with the same name. Now it gives me error when I try to create the app with the same name.

[image: Error I receive while creating app]

Comment: Did you find out what you needed to do or have a contact number?

Comment: No it never solved. The Apple rep said, this is a kind of scenario where you have lost the name. You can not reuse the name any more. I ended up using the name appending "s" to it.

Comment: Questions about iTunes Connect are currently considered outside the scope of what is on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling Apple, their rep said, this is a kind of scenario where you have lost the name. You can not reuse the name any more. I ended up using a new name appending "s" to it.

Comment: You Apple is a POS. I had the same issue and they said why did you call before you removed the app....Well because you were closed and I had to get stuff accomplished. Fix your crappy website Apple

Comment: You're so right. I have my personal developer account and as my employer wanted to add me to his team account once, it got into deadlock and my account was dead. They recreated my account afterwards. Thanks to God I had no application by that time.

Comment: I spent about 10 hours to get this uploaded. Their webpage is so broken

Answer (score 2):

You have to contact iTunes Connect, they'll have it already in their system that your app took the name first, but as you've tried to recreate it with the same name the system is assuming the other is valid (but with errors) and bouncing you. There's a support email address for them, they'll either be able to pull the old one and let you take the spot, or advise you on what you need to do.

Comment: I had a thought of it. I am going to call Apple today.

Comment: It's the best bet really, if there's a conflict on their systems you're kind of stuck until they can fix it.